Converting cumulative (weekly) rates into non-cumulative (monthly) rates
I have this dataset here which cumulative weekly covid-19 death rates in Canada (scroll to bottom of page): https://health-infobase.canada.ca/covid-19/
I download it in R (note that this is the death rate in the general population, not death rate of the infected population):
temp_file <- tempfile()
download.file(
    url = "https://health-infobase.canada.ca/src/data/covidLive/covid19-download.csv",
    destfile = temp_file
)

covid_data <- read.csv(temp_file)

I make this plot for the cumulative weekly death rate of different provinces:
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales) 

ggplot(covid_data, aes(x = as.Date(date), y = ratedeaths, color = prname)) +
    # Add lines for each province
    geom_line(linewidth = 1) +
    
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
        legend.position = "right",
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.title = element_text(face = "bold")
    ) +
    
    labs(
        title = "COVID-19 Death Rates Over Time by Province",
        subtitle = "Deaths per 100,000 population",
        x = "Date",
        y = "Death Rate",
        color = "Province"
    ) +
    
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 months", date_labels = "%b %Y") +
    
    scale_color_viridis_d()


I then made it non-cumulative weekly:
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)

covid_data <- covid_data %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
    group_by(prname) %>%
    arrange(date) %>%
    mutate(daily_death_rate = ratedeaths - lag(ratedeaths, default = first(ratedeaths))) %>%
    mutate(daily_death_rate = pmax(daily_death_rate, 0))

ggplot(covid_data, aes(x = date, y = daily_death_rate, color = prname)) +
    # Add lines for each province
    geom_line(linewidth = 1) +
    
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
        legend.position = "right",
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.title = element_text(face = "bold")
    ) +
    
    labs(
        title = "Daily COVID-19 Death Rates by Province",
        subtitle = "Daily deaths per 100,000 population",
        x = "Date",
        y = "Daily Death Rate",
        color = "Province"
    ) +
    
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 months", date_labels = "%b %Y") +
    
    scale_color_viridis_d()


I actually want this to be monthly averages, so I again transformed it to now non-cumulative monthly:
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(lubridate)  


covid_data_monthly <- covid_data %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
    mutate(year_month = floor_date(date, "month")) %>%
    group_by(prname) %>%
    arrange(date) %>%
    mutate(daily_death_rate = ratedeaths - lag(ratedeaths, default = first(ratedeaths))) %>%
    mutate(daily_death_rate = pmax(daily_death_rate, 0)) %>%
    group_by(prname, year_month) %>%
    summarise(
        monthly_avg_death_rate = mean(daily_death_rate, na.rm = TRUE),
        .groups = "drop"
    )

ggplot(covid_data_monthly, 
       aes(x = year_month, y = monthly_avg_death_rate, color = prname)) +
    geom_line(linewidth = 1) +
    geom_point(size = 2) +
    
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
        legend.position = "right",
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.title = element_text(face = "bold")
    ) +
    
    labs(
        title = "Monthly Average COVID-19 Death Rates by Province",
        subtitle = "Average daily deaths per 100,000 population, by month",
        x = "Date",
        y = "Average Daily Death Rate",
        color = "Province"
    ) +
    
    scale_x_date(
        date_breaks = "2 months", 
        date_labels = "%b %Y"
    ) +
    
    scale_color_viridis_d()


I am just wondering: from a statistical point of view, is the process of converting weekly cumulative rates to monthly non-cumulative rates correct? I think it is simple enough, but I am not sure if I made some mistake doing this.

Are you asking if the math you preformed is correct or did you have some sort of model or statistical test in mind?

I am just wondering if when provided cumulative rates at one time interval, it is possible to to make them as non-cumulative rates at some other time interval?

Very few readers will want to read your code and run it just to figure out whether you're asking an answerable question.  Based on this last comment, which seems to provide some clues about what you're asking, I can't help thinking that such a basic question could be formulated in a couple of lines: could you try to do that?

In general, if you have cumulative count data recorded at a fixed interval you can take first differences to calculate the instantaneous measurement at the same interval. The reverse is also true and going from instantaneous records to cumulative records is trivial.
Even more general, the interval doesn't need to be fixed to switch between these two representations of the data. I won't refer to intervals for the remainder of this answer. Instead I will refer to the reporting time as a timestamp. In your case I believe the resolution of the timestamp is 1 week but the information below holds at other resolutions such as seconds or milliseconds.
You can't report the data at times other than the original timestamps without introducing assumptions and uncertainty regardless of which representation is being used. For example, say your weekly data contains with the weekly counts ending at the same day/time every week. You introduce some inaccuracy by reporting monthly. Only some months will end on the same day as your weekly data. This means that some counts for that week will be in one month and the remaining counts will fall in a different month and you don't actually know what that split should be. You can try to address this by adding some assumptions/data models. For example you could assume the daily count data is uniform in each weekly record. At this point you are starting to get into the territory of synchronization and imputation of time series data which is a broad topic.
It isn't clear what analysis you plan to do with the data so it isn't clear if the errors introduced by going from weekly to monthly matter. My suggestion is to stick with the timestamps you have if possible. You will have more observations to apply to whatever time series models you had in mind.
